# Can't find all translatable strings in strings.xml - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I have a strange problem - in application source code I bought recently - there is strings.xml file inside Android Project files, off course, but...not all strings which are present within application are in strings.xml file, and I can't find them anywhere within app.

So, I have full sentences within app, tried even "double shift" but - no way, I can't find them, thus - can't translate them, so I have CROATIAN language, but some parts of app are still in ENGLISH language, but those strings are not in english strings.xml (default language off app is English).

Any help appreciated...thank you

EDIT:

I found one of the strings:

```
initializeToolbar(title: "Transactions")
```

How to represent this, for example, in strings.xml, so that can be translatable?

Answer (score 0):

we have to make strings.xml based on language and put into corresponding values

For example

Spanish strings (es locale),

```
res/values-es/strings.xml
```

French  strings,

```
res/values-fr/strings.xml
```

Japanese - strings

```
res/values-ja/strings.xml
```

for more details read [Localize](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Answer (score 0):

If they didn't put the strings in strings.xml, you won't be able to translate them.  You'll need to find the strings in the actual app, and move them one by one to strings.xml by adding them and replacing them in the code with Resources.getString calls or resource id references.  This is actually very common when the code is written quickly and the developers aren't disciplined about their string usage.

Comment: That's horrible, my God :( there's a "billion" untranslated strings in such way, you're sure ther's no "quicker" way to do that?

Comment: It isn't that bad difficulty wise, just tedious.  You might be able to speed things up by looking for setText calls and validating those, as that's what most text will be put to the screen using.  But it won't be exhaustive.  This is the kind of thing where you're going to fix 90% of it up front, and the rest 1 string at a time as you find them.